# Derivative of $f(t-kx)$

Tags: partial-derivative

If I have a function $f(t-kx)$ where $k$ is a constant and $t$ and $x$ are variables, then I know by looking at it that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=-(1/k)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ since it's obvious that changing $x$ is equivalent to changing $t$.

How do I show this formally? What is the right terminology for this type of problem and solution, and can it be generalized to more complicated cases like $f=f(u(t,x))$ for some function $u$?

Alternatively using $u=t-kx$ I can try $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$, and since $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=1$ this gives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ which is not helpful, but if I apply the chain rule twice then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$, for the simple case $u=t-kx$, I can find $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}=-(1/k)$ but it seems this is only possible if the function $u(t,x)$ is invertible for $x$?

Comment: You want to read up about the chain rule!

Comment: I tried that first but no progress, I updated the question to show my attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$u=t-kx$$

$$\frac {\partial {f}}{\partial t}=\frac {\partial {f}}{\partial u}.\frac {\partial u}{\partial t} =\frac {\partial {f}}{\partial u}$$
Similarly you find $$\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac {\partial {f}}{\partial u}.\frac {\partial u}{\partial x}=-k\frac {\partial {f}}{\partial u}$$

You can take over from here.

Comment: That expresses the derivative w.r.t. to t in terms of a derivative w.r.t. u, but I'm trying to express it w.r.t. x.

Comment: @kotozna after finding both derivatives you can find the ratio and come up with the answer. $ \frac {\partial f }{\partial u}$ cancels out.

Comment: @kotozna check my edited solution. It makes it easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I show this formally? What is the right terminology for this type of problem and solution, and can it be generalized to more complicated cases...

Someone has shown you how to deduce this formally.

This is the method for differentiating composite functions, and it is known as the chain rule (in multivariable calculus). Yes, you're right -- we can use it to differentiate any composition of functions that are each differentiable.